# Overflow hidden issue on horizontal scrolling site

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scrolling site with two sections as 100% width/height divs wrapped in a 200% width/ 100% height div. It uses jquery to resize the main div to the size of the browser, this way keeping each section separate with the browser at any size. To make the scrolling work, I have set the overflow on the 100% div to hidden however I need the page to be scrollable when the browser window is shrunk to to certain point because otherwise content cannot be seen/accessed.

Here is a link to test page: http://jamesisfishing.com/albertst/tester.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

Just after the `<body>` insert this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;min-width:1000px;"></div>
```

Then, add to your `<div id="wrapper">` a `min-width:1000px`

This forces the first div to a minimum width of 1000px, keeping the content to 1000px too and showing scrollbars for the first div.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even need the extra div, was just the min-height on the #wrapper that did it. Simple.